# Laravel: Invalid argument supplied foreach()

Tags: php, github, laravel, oauth, laravel-4

Working with a project that uses OAuth user registration through GitHub. Everything is working fine until the last step of confirming the account through my application.

[image]

Here is the function in question:

```
/**
 * Get the primary, verified email address from the Github data.
 *
 * @param  mixed $emails
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function getPrimaryEmail($emails)
{
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        if (! $email->primary) {
            continue;
        }

        if ($email->verified) {
            return $email->email;
        }

        throw new GithubEmailNotVerifiedException;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Anyone else ever experience this when working with OAuth and GitHub? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to be an arse, but it sounds like emails is not an array. Is it possibly a `null`?

Log the actual value with `Log::debug('WTF IS THIS THEN?!!: '.print_r($emails, true));` and see.

Comment: Typical... Thank you Phil. It is indeed null. I should have checked that but I assumed my code was working. At least one of us was observant. ;)